# The Uri for the target storage location is not specified. Please consider changing the request's location mode

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am making a call to a secondary endpoint of a RAGRS enabled Azure storage account. I set the location mode of the blob client as Secondary only. But  the get servicestats call fails with the following storage exception :
The Uri for the target storage location is not specified. Please consider changing the request's location mode.
What I am possibly missing?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your code so the community can help you ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which method you used to set the location mode, I refer to multiple docs. There are mainly three methods, I tested them , however only one method works.

These two articles are what I have tested. First [doc](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2013/12/11/windows-azure-storage-redundancy-options-and-read-access-geo-redundant-storage/#_Introducing_Read-only_Access) and second [doc](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/14fa1973-9eb0-4465-835a-aecc566625e8/error-the-uri-for-the-target-storage-location-is-not-specified-please-consider-changing-the?forum=windowsazuredevelopment).

This is my test code and it works, I also use Fiddler to capture the endpoint.

```
// Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        queueClient.DefaultRequestOptions.LocationMode = LocationMode.SecondaryOnly;

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

        // Peek at the next message
        CloudQueueMessage peekedMessage = queue.PeekMessage();

        // Display message.
        Console.WriteLine(peekedMessage.AsString);
```

[image]

**Note: use the StorageConnectionString you get in the portal, don't change it.**

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: @Amritendu Shekhar Dhar,any more questions, if it's helpful, you could accept it as the answer.